# Non linear programming please HELP

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

[image]Hey guys, I never do that but just found out that I have an assignment due in a few hours..thought it was for later, any help/solutions for this one?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a starter: the Lagrangian $ L = R(y,a) + \mu_1(R(y,a) - C(y) -a -m) + \mu_2a + \mu3y$